# jquery json array Googlemap

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, google-maps

Got probs with a nice exmaple. I used this Google map example and it is working with the local array created in the javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/jFMQ5/2/

Now I just need to alter it to get the array from php.

Steps are

- create array in php
- convert array to json using json_encode
- grap it in javascript

**Question...** how to iterate over json and not array. OR how to create a javascript array from json

In my javascript I got this (also full of charset errors, but I guess that is another problem)

```
var arrAddress = ["Sir vej 3 7500 Holstebro","Ivar Lundgaardsvej 8 7500 Holstebro","H\u00f8jtoftvej 6 7500 Holstebro","Svalev\u00e6nget 22 7500 Holstebro","Ringk\u00f8bingvej 21 7500 Holstebro","Elkj\u00e6rvej 90 7500 Holstebro","Hovedgaden 2 7500 Holstebro","Skolegade 32 7500 Holstebro","Fuglsangvej 2 7500 Holstebro","Sl\u00e5envej 150 7500 Holstebro","Burvej 2A Idom 7500 Holstebro"];
```

In the jsfiddle example it expecting an array like this:

```
$arrAddress[0] = "Sir vej 3 7500 Holstebro";
$arrAddress[1] = "Ivar Lundgaardsvej 8 7500 Holstebro"
etc. etc.
```

How to make the jsfiddle link work with this json string in stead of the local defined array?

**UPDATE**
PHP is creating the array like this:

```
// in PHP //
While(...) {
    $arrAddress[] = $row['address'].' '.$row['zip'].' '.$row['city'];
}
// after while
$arrAddress = json_encode($arrAddress);
// end php //

// in javascript //
var addAddress = {$arrAddress}
```

Comment: How you iterate over the JSON depends on how it's formatted. Can you give an example of how your PHP is creating it.

Comment: sure. I will update it. But the arrAddress is equal to the json from the php

Comment: So you're retuning an array in string format, instead of JSON?

Comment: That is just one attempt. I will do what ever is needed. I take a php array, convert it to jason and try to reaD THAT json using javascript. Nevere read json before, I guess the problem is doing that

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're returning a JSON object in your javascript?  Try doing a `console.log(addAddress)` and see if it's returning a string or an object.  This is will also show you the "array" indexes (in Chrome anyway).

Try parsing the json string as well

```
var addAddress = $.parseJSON({$arrAddress});
```